# How to make an X plot or a plot where negative and positive values cross

Tags: python

Plot the lists x=[1,2,…,100] and y=[1,2,…,100] with a black line and the lists x=[1,2,…,100] and
y=[100,99,98,…,1] with gray dots in the same Figure.[I think this could help to ilustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t71Xv.png)

I have already made the first linea, but I don´t know what function or library could be used. I leave the code here.

```
x = list(range(100))
y = list(range(100))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(x,y, linestyle='-', color='black')
```

Comment: Try `plt.plot(x, y, x, y[::-1])`?